# Is there a way to control visibility of the SWIG generated JNI class?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

By default, SWIG generates the JNI class with public visibility.  Is there a way to specify that the JNI class is only accessible within the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  The following will set the visibility to just the package:

```
%pragma(java) jniclassclassmodifiers="class"
```

See:

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_imclass_pragmas